# Devise asking for "router_name" for partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, omniauth

Hi am creating a Devise login form on the index page of my app

Err: "undefined method `router_name' for nil:NilClass"

```
    <%= form_for("user", :url => new_user_session_path, :html => {:class => "cd-form"}) do |f| %>
      <%- flash.each do |name, msg| -%>
        <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" if msg.is_a?(String) %>
      <%- end -%>
      <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :email, :class => 'image-replace cd-username' %><br />
        <%= f.email_field :email, :class => 'full-width has-padding has-border', autofocus: true %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password %>
        <% if @validatable %>
        <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
        <% end %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password, :class => 'full-width has-padding has-border', autocomplete: "off" %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password_confirmation, :class => 'image-replace cd-password-2' %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :class => 'full-width has-padding has-border', autocomplete: "off" %>
      </div>

      <%= render "users/shared/links" %>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Sign up", :class => 'full-width has-padding' %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

I followed the guide:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app

I am not using a Mountable engine nor do I intend to.

Following other guides,  I also put this in my controller

```
def resource_name
    :user
end

def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
end

def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
end
...
```

Adding this to suppress the error

```
...
def router_name
end
```

I don't see a need to configure it in devise.rb

Comment: Did you find anything to solve this? I'm having this issue in a view spec.

Answer (score 0):

You have declarate

> <%= form_for("user"

(string) instead

> <%= form_for(:user

(object)

Comment: Private repo.  Thanks.  I'll keep Googling

Comment: This should not make any difference in the resulting code

Answer (score 0):

I caused the same error by renaming `/views/user` to `/views/users` (adding an `s`).

Changing it back resolved the issue.

This likely won't solve for everyone but might help some people.